# Unique ID/SOAP header format question

Tags: c#, soap

I'm having an issue with a specification change outside of my environment.  We have an application that sends SOAP messages, and the message ID is a Unique ID that we generate on every new message.

The message ID appears as urn:uuid:########

The problem is that the receiving side no longer accepts message ids with the prefixed "urn:uuid"

How can I remove that prefix before or after setting that as the messageID?

Comment: You'll have to change your code to remove the prefix. We can't help you change your code unless you show us your code.

Comment: @John Saunders The code for generating the id is really simple (might be part of the problem): `soapMessage.Headers.MessageId = new UniqueID();`

Comment: What is the full type name of `UniqueId`?

Comment: @John Saunders `System.XML.UniqueID`

Comment: Apologies, I may have lost my marbles for a moment.  I believe this can be set by passing a guid into the constructor as a string.

`Guid guID = new Guid();
 UniqueId unID = new UniqueId(guID.ToString());

soapMessage.Headers.MessageId = unID;
`

Better solutions would still be helpful, but I think this is passable.

Comment: What does `new UniqueId().ToString()` result in?

Answer (score 3):

This turned out to be a really simple solution:

`UniqueId unID = new UniqueId(); 
soapMessage.Headers.MessageId = new UniqueID(unID.ToString().Substring(9));`

Don't ask me why I couldn't figure this out before asking, and thanks to John Saunders for asking for the full type name and thus pointing out my stupidity.